# Unity: Spawn object from client to all clients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a Player that shoots Bullets, but the Bullets are only being Spawned to all clients when the Player that shoots is the Host.

Using **Unity 5.6**

What I have so far...

- I already have the Prefab registered in the NetworkManager.
- The Prefab has a **NetworkIdentity** with **ServerOnly** in **false** and **LocalPlayerAuthority** in **false**.
- The Prefab has a **NetworkTransform** with a **NetworkSendRate = 0** and a **TransformSyncMode** to **Sync RigidBody2D**.
- The Player shoots the Bullet with a method **[Command]** and using **NetworkServer.Spawn (bulletInstance)**

  - Before the **NetworkServer.Spawn** is called I assign the **velocity** to the **RigidBody2D** of the bulletInstance.
  - The Bullet Script Class is a **NetworkBehaviour**
  - Player has **NetworkIdentity** with **LocalPlayerAuthority** in true
  - Player Script Class is a **NetworkBehaviour**

[image]

Comment: Have you add networkidentiy in bulletPrefab ?? Second way you can use a method with [RpcClient] RpcSpawnABullet(vector) into [Command]CmdFire.

Comment: you check this? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetCustomSpawning.html

Comment: how did you call cmdFire

Answer (score 3):

In Unet,

## 1. Only the SERVER can spawn any object - end of story

In Unet, servers spawn objects and that's it. End of story.

## 2. You HAVE TO HAVE "player" objects. Every client absolutely MUST have a "player" object.

It's totally normal that the "player" object is not actually a tank or biped - but is simply **an empty game object**. (Sometimes called an "abstract player object").

Every client MUST have a "player object" - often just **an empty game object**

## 3. Regarding spawning objects which have client authority - see point 1.

It's very easy to spawn objects with client authority. Just go to the doco page Manual/UNetSpawning.html and scroll down to
Code (CSharp):

```
NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(treeGo, conn);
```

It is explained there (really that's all there is to it).

## 4. Say some specific player, X, will have the authority over the object. Of course, you can't spawn the object until X has joined!

In the line of code just above, people often ask **how the hell do you know which "conn" `NetworkConnection` to use**?

Of course, it is meaningless until X has actually joined the game! See point 2!

So you might do things like this...

> Example 1 - only one specific client is your "mothership". Of course, the server must, obviously, know the `NetworkConnection` to that client. You'll have it saved in a variable `networkConnectionToMothership`. Thus, in this example, you have the "conn" to use.

or

> Example 2 - a client (say, client JohnSmith) wants to spawn an object which JohnSmith will have authority over. Quite simply, the client (JohnSmith) asks the server to spawn the object. "Asks the server" simply means send a `Command`.

Inside any "Command" (ie, running on the server) you literally have the property `connectionToClient` which gives you the "conn" needed!

So that's the deal.

For this specific question, in your code you are calling `NetworkServer.spawn`.

You should be calling

```
NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(treeGo, conn);
```

(Search for that on this doco page: Manual/UNetSpawning.html  )

and I have explained above in example (2) how you would know what "conn" to use.